# Laravel, Dropzone "Trying to get property of non-object" File upload error

Tags: php, file-upload, laravel, laravel-4, dropzone.js

I am working on a project that needs file uploading. I have implemented Dropzone.js
and Laravel Framework. I am sure I have setup everything correctly, but when I drop the files to dropzone and they finish upload I get this error

```
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Call to a member function getRealPath() on a non-object","file":"C:\\wamp\\www\\local\\app\\controllers\\AssetsController.php","line":119}}
```

This is my route

```
Route::post('create/album','AssetsController@album');
```

This is my Controller

```
$path = "assets";
$fileee = Input::file('file');
Image::make($fileee->getRealPath())->resize(500, null, true)->save($path);
```

When i check with laravel if there is a file it returns NULL but when i var_dump() the Input::file() i get an array of file related data, I have searched the web and cant seem to find anything.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Call to a member function getRealPath() on a non-object is the key here. $fileee is not an object. You answered this yourself when you said it's an array.

Comment: @Dave no laravel docs are not wrong, i am using a package to handle photo upload http://intervention.olivervogel.net/image/getting_started/laravel

Comment: @Dave getRealPath() is a function of that image class i am using

Comment: Well, if $fileee is an array (as you said it is) then either a) the docs are wrong or b) something is preventing you from getting the object back that it claims you should.

Comment: Your error is self explanatory, $fileee is not an object. It has no methods. It is an array. Figure out why it's an array instead of the File object it claims it should be and you're set.

Comment: @skrilled i think this has something to do with dropzone.js, because when i upload files with normal form i do not get this error

Comment: Normal form being how symfony builds a form correct?

Comment: @skrilled i do not understand?

Comment: You said it works when you use normal form. Do you mean symfony's form builder or are you creating your own html-based form tags in the view?

Comment: The opening and closing form tags are generated by symphony, i only write the choose file and submit button myself

Comment: @skrilled i fixed the issue, i have answered my question below, thankyou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured out how to fix this, this is what got it fixed this is my changed Controller

```
    $fileee = Input::file('file');
    Image::make($fileee[0]->getRealPath())->resize(540, null, true)->save('assets/example.png');
```

If anyone is asking where did those image manipulation methods came from this is the class iam using http://intervention.olivervogel.net/image/getting_started/laravel

Hope this helps someone in the fututre

Answer (score 0):

I also searched for an answer but got a solution.

Dropzone has this setting:

```
uploadMultiple: true
```

If you set it to `true`, it forms an array that's why you needed to do `$fileee[0]`. If you allow only one image to be sent, change it to `false` and you will get an object.